# Docker Swarm does not support use of GPU devices

Tags: docker-compose, gpu, docker-swarm, nvidia-docker

I am trying to deploy GPU workload into my swarm cluster.

My service manifest looks like this.

```
nvidia:
    image: "tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./ubuntu_gpu
        target: /app
        consistency: cached
    build:
      context: ./ubuntu_gpu
    ports:
      - 6186:80
    working_dir: "/app"
    runtime: nvidia
    environment:
      - LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/targets/x86_64-linux/lib
   deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            capabilities: [gpu]
```

The approach described above was taken from docker official documentation on GPU support
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/

When I deploy the stack, I get this error below.

```
Additional property devices is not allowed
```

It seems like docker swarm does not have visibility of the GPU device attached to the worker node.

Does anyone know if this feature works only docker-compose but not docker-swarm or if there is a work around this ?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, docker swarmkit does not seem to support `devices`, see this [issue on the docker github](https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1244), there is quite the longstanding discussion around it.

Comment: One way to use GPU in docker (even swarm) is to use nvidia/cuda docker images. They are shipped with drivers included.

Comment: To my understanding the issue is with the way docker swarm addresses hardware, which can not be circumvented on a stack/service level. Of course you can run arbitrary independent services on single nodes by directly using `docker compose` on that node, but that defeats the purpose of docker swarm.

Comment: Is it now possible to use `docker swarm` with nvidia gpus?